# Is there any alernatives for execute INSERT query from main_db stored procedure to a log table in another database

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Trying to keep log of a table. At every update time i need to insert the row that is being updated into log table

main table and log table are created in separate databases.

Is there any alternative/ More optimized version of solution for this use-case.

Here provided dummy database, stored procedure which does the job of my use-case
In this approach

1. Need to explicitly pass connection string
2. Right now connection string hard coded. But it's not very convenient.

------ MAIN DATABASE -----

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_test (
        pk_test_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        vhr_test_value VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT ''
);
```

------ LOG DATABASE -----

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_test_log (
        pk_test_log_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        fk_test_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
        vhr_test_value VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT ''
);
```

---- INSERTING TO LOG TABLE -----

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_insert_or_update_to_test_log() AS $$
    DECLARE
        insert_statement TEXT;
        
    BEGIN

        insert_statement = $Q1$ INSERT INTO tbl_test_log (fk_test_id, vhr_test_value)
                                SELECT pk_test_id, vhr_test_value
                                FROM dblink('host=192.168.1.3 port=5432 user=postgres password=admin dbname=main_db',
                                            'SELECT pk_test_id, vhr_test_value FROM tbl_test WHERE pk_test_id=1')
                                     AS ct(pk_test_id BIGINT, vhr_test_value VARCHAR) $Q1$;

        dblink_exec('host=192.168.1.3 port=5432 user=postgres password=admin dbname=db_log', insert_statement, true);
        RETURN;
    
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
     
     
CALL sp_insert_or_update_to_test_log(); -- Executed from main database.
```

Comment: Use a foreign table and a trigger (and trigger function)

Comment: This method worked. 
[postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html)